# Sorting rows in two dimensional arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, sorting, perl

I am trying to sort a two dimensional array in perl.

I know I can sort the rows by a key-column with

```
@array = sort { $a->[0] cmp  $b->[0] } @array
```

but I need to sort it the other way: sort the columns by a key-row.

Is there a quick way to do this, other than coding a complete sorting function?

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, sorting columns of a `2D` array is not as straightforward as sorting rows. There is no built-in function for this purpose. but We transpose the `2D` array, sort it and then transpose it back as below ,

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip6 unzip6);

# 2D array
my @array = (
    [4, 3, 2],
    [1, 6, 8],
    [7, 5, 9]
);

# Transpose the array
my @transposed = zip6 @array;

# Sort the transposed array on the first row
@transposed = sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @transposed;

# Transpose it back
@array = unzip6 @transposed;

# Print the sorted array
for my $row (@array) {
    print join(" ", @$row), "\n";
}
```

here `zip6` and `unzip6` functions from `List::MoreUtils` module are used for transposing the array. If you are working with a larger array, you can use PDL, which provides more efficient handling of large datasets.

Comment: The transposing is a good idea. But the `zip6` and `unzip6` cannot be found: Could not find sub 'zip6' exported by List::MoreUtils at test.pl line 3.        BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.

Comment: Your specific version may not include the zip6 and unzip6 function. You may try zip and unzip instead.

Comment: The [zip6](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#zip6) does not work like that  (`zip6 @a1, @a2`), and there is no `unzip6`. See the actual documentation. @LjmDullaart,  One _can_ use them to accomplish this idea but not the way it's shown

Comment: Did the transpose with two nested loops. Gave an upvote for the transpose idea.